# Данные или размер приложения после установки

Tags: android

Такая проблема, делал приложение пару месяцев, регулярно его тестировал, но перед тем как залить в маркет установил рекламу адмоб, к слову мое первое приложение, так после установки рекламы заметил такую вещь, данные приложения после каждого запуска набирают в весе, в версии без рекламы такого не происходит. Можете объяснить в чем дело и как это исправить??? (вес почти 20, но как то дошло до 30мб, соответственно хочу исправить)

Answer (score 1):

AdMob [кэширует](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198107/android-admob-unexpected-data-storage-and-cache-values) рекламную информацию в целях экономии трафика.

Comment: если я правильно понял англ, то это исправить невозможно? только у меня вес не кэш падает а именно в данные

Comment: @Дима, кеширует он их, как данные. Если очень хочется, можете посмотреть при помощи root, как и куда он их кеширует (путь **data/data/<your_application_package>**), и удалять этот кеш например при запуске приложения.

Comment: @metalurgus, а не подскажете как это сделать? нюанс, у меня при самом первом запуске идет выбор и сохранение главного activity (SharedPreferences), мне нужно что бы эти данные не терялись после удаления, потому что, если делать вручную "очистить данные", идет сброс

Comment: @Дима, получите рут доступ на своем устройстве, и посмотрите. Скорее всего, он кеширует в какую-то свою папку просто. Вот эту папку и нужно удалять. Как удалить папку:https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20delete%20directory%20programmatically&es_th=1